# Change Add to Cart Button When ACF Has Value on WooCommerce Product Archive

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to change the Add to Cart button when a product has an ACF (Advanced Custom Fields) value on WooCommerce product archive. For instance if my field named `mix_and_match_enabled` is switched on, I need the button to read "View options" and link to the product page instead of the default "Add to cart" button.

Here's some sample code of how I believe this could be done but it's likely wrong.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'replace_default_button', 10, 2 );
function replace_default_button( $button, $product ){
    $mix_and_match = get_post_meta($post_id, 'mix_and_match_enabled', true);

    if ( $mix_and_match ){
        $button = '<a href="#" class="button alt">' . __( "View options", "woocommerce" ) . '</a>';
    }
    return $button;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe I've solved my issue. I've pasted the solution below. Please feel free to improve on this code.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'replace_default_button', 10, 2 );
function replace_default_button( $button, $product ){
    $mix_and_match = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'mix_and_match_enabled', true);

    if ( $mix_and_match == 1 ){
        $button = '<a href="' . get_permalink($product_id) . ' " class="button alt">' . __( "View options", "woocommerce" ) . '</a>';
    }
    return $button;
}
```